# Magento 1.9 USPS First-Class Package Service - Retail not working

Tags: magento-1.9, usps

I am not getting **USPS First class shipping method** at **checkout page**.

I had tried [that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/191492/60352) link but no luck can anyone help to solve this issue

Comment: @KamranKhan could you please help

Comment: check this link    https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151510/magento-2-how-to-get-all-active-shipping-methods

Comment: @KamranKhan I am getting all other shipping methods but I am not getting only USPS First class shipping method

Comment: Can anyone help me

Comment: I would suggest you to ask the same question again with all the relevant code, because its not easy to tell the solution without looking at the code.